# Configurable product sorting by ID in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, associated-products

I have Magento 1.9.2 and a configurable product with size options (S,M,L,XL) those options are associated simple products. At the moment Magento is sorting the options by ID.

Is there anyway to sort by a specified order that I give?

Comment: are you need sort by a specified order in admin side or front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to

> Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute

Edit your attribute *(SIZE)* and set Used for Sorting in Product Listing to *(YES)*.